# Как корректно указать дополнительный путь для gcc?

Tags: linux, c, gcc

Я новичек в этом. Я использую Linux и *gcc* в *bash*.

Имеется:

- p1.c:

  ```
  int func()
  {
    return 1889; 
  }
  ```
- func.h:

  ```
  #ifndef ONCE
  #define ONCE
  int func();
  #endif
  ```
- p2.c:

  ```
  #include <stdio.h>
  #include <func.h>

  int main()
  {
      int a = func();
      printf("%d",a);
      return 0;
  }
  ```

`func.h` я специально переместил в другую папку. В `*.bashrc*` дописал `export PATH="$PATH:/root/deleteme/spec"`

```
# echo $PATH
/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/lib/jvm/default/bin:/usr/bin/site_perl:/usr/bin/vendor_perl:/usr/bin/core_perl:/root/deleteme/spec
```

---

```
# gcc p?.c
```

*вывод:*

> ```
> p2.c:2:18: fatal error: func.h: No such file or directory
>  #include <func.h>
>                  ^
> compilation terminated.
> ```

Заработало при указании `gcc -I`.

**Почему не работает через переменную окружения? Хочется разобраться как это работает. Спасибо :)**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Переменная окружения `$PATH`, содержащая пути где исполняемые файлы (скрипты, программы) лежат, не имеет отношения к путям, в которых gcc ищет заголовочные файлы (`*.h`).

Есть [директории по умолчанию такие как `/usr/include`](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Search-Path.html), например, используемые для  библиотек, установленных из `*-dev` системных пакетов.

Распространенный способ указать свои пути к заголовочным файлам это использовать `-I` опцию. Если хочется, можно определить [соответствующие переменные окружения (`CPATH`, etc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Environment-Variables.html). 
Если использовать `"func.h"`, а не `<func.h>`, то `func.h` сперва ищется в  директории с текущим файлом (`p2.c`). [Существуют и другие (менее используемые) опции, контролирующие как заголовки ищутся](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Invocation.html#Invocation).

Comment: CPATH задал (через bash ведь надо?), gcc все равно ругается

Comment: @MikeAJ, исправьте дописанное вами в `.bashrc`, заменив `PATH` на `CPATH`, и перезапустите сеанс оболочки. экспортирована ли переменная, можно проверить, например, так: `echo $CPATH`. // не стоит пользовательские задачи выполнять из-под административного аккаунта (*root*).

Comment: Спасибо, это работает. А чем отличается `CPATH` от `C_INCLUDE_PATH`?

Comment: @MikeAJ: я бы вообще переменных окружения не использовал, а нужные `-I` опции в Makefile (или IDE, etc) задавал. Иначе компилируя чужой код вам придётся беспокоится не конфликтуют ли ваши заголовки с этим кодом (где "чужой код" может быть даже ваш же код, но через полгода, когда детали текущего проекта уже подзабыты).

Comment: Ок,спс. А для чего пишут `#include "func.h"` прямо в самом `p1.c`. Ведь этот include тут не необходим?

Comment: @MikeAJ: вопрос почему файл, содержащий определение функции, включает файл, содержащий объявление (декларацию) функции, можно задать в виде отдельного SO вопроса.

Comment: Прошу прощения за такой глупый вопрос. В общем случае я знаю для чего включают декларацию, а в таком простом файле определения-нет. 
Понятия не имею что такое SO вопрос.

Comment: @MikeAJ SO это Stack Overflow—сайт вопросов и ответов, на котором вы находитесь. `p1.c` в вопросе явно содержит определение `func()` функции, а `func.h` содержит декларацию. Поэтому если вы знаете зачем в общем случае декларацию включают в файл, содержащий определение функции, то должно быть ясно зачем в p1.c помеcтить func.h